# Update Parse ACL on queried object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, acl, parse-server

In my iOS app I am making a PFObject and saving it to Parse. Later, a user's account is created (which didn't exist before), and tries to modify it but can't because the PFObjects's ACL wasn't set to allow that user to have permission. How can I modify the ACL of an existing object in Parse to allow this user to have access? I *do not* want to allow public write access.

The following code prints `Success!` if given the right `code` query parameter, but when I check the ACL in Parse it has not been updated at all.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Bike")
query.whereKey("bikeID", equalTo: code)
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
    guard let obj = objects?[0], error == nil else {
        print("Error")
        return
    }
    obj.acl?.setWriteAccess(true, for: PFUser.current()!)
    obj.saveInBackground { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            print("Success!")
        }
    }
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34684458/7102572) seems to suggest that the ACL cannot be changed through my app's Swift code.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the object you want to grant access to up-front you can change it's ACL in the CloudCode `afterSave` hook of the `User` class: in `afterSave`, test whether the user was just created (to avoid redoing this work for subsequent save requests), then look up the object and set the access rights using the master key.